# DataSet with DataTables vs Dictionary with DataTables

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

What combination is less memory hungry:

A **DatatSet with multiple DataTables** or a **Dictionary with multiple DataTables**?

I only need a Collection of DataTables, the whole functions of a DataSet is not required...

Comment: Why don't you try and see?

Comment: The difference will be negligible, so i would use a DataSet since it's the appropriate container for multiple tables. But you could also use a `DataTable[]` or `List<DataTable>`. It's up to you.

Comment: I'm also placing my bet for the DataSet. But it's always nice to check (to be honest, I don't really expect much of a difference)

Comment: A dictionary only makes a copy of the keys and not the values.  The value in a dictionary are links.  Changing the values in a dictionary will change the value in the source datatable(s).

Answer (score 3):

The difference will be negligible, so i would use a `DataSet` since it's the appropriate container for multiple tables. But you could also use a `DataTable[]` or `List<DataTable>`. It's up to you.

In terms of memory consumption the difference (if any) is irrelevant. Chose the type of collection which is most appropriate for your task. If you need to lookup the table by name use a `DataSet` or `Dictionary<string, DataTable>`. If you just need a collection for multiple tables chose `IList<DataTable>`(array or list). As already stated, i would use a `DataSet` because it's the natural collection for DataTables.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers! To be honest, I thought using a DataSet would be more expensive because of the powerfull methods...